# turning $2x$ into a perfect even

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, recursive-algorithms, even-and-odd-functions

So I am trying to generate a sequence with an equation (that I don't think exists) and it involves all the even numbers, and one way to find the sequence is to get rid of all odd prime numbers so...

$2\frac{x}{n_k}$ where $n_m$ is $x$ without any $2$'s in its prime factorization.

then I tried to make an equation for $n_k$.

$n_m=n_{m-1}(\frac{(n_{m-1}\mod{2})+1}2)$
where $n_1=x$
or
$n_m=n_{m-1}(\frac{3-\cos(\pi n_{m-1})}{4})$
where $n_1=x$

now that I have a recursive formula I was wondering if any one could make a standard formula from this (and show how you did it if you want)

Comment: Are you trying to list all numbers without $2$ in their prime factorization? If so, just list all the odd integers

Comment: @gt6989b no, I'm not I am trying to get a sequence from this, 1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,... you can get this by seeing how many $2$'s are in each even number 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16

Comment: So what are you trying to do?

Comment: accidentally replied too early

Comment: So, if we were to include the odd numbers in this list, this would be $a_n$ is the maximum integer value of $k$ such that $2^k$ divides evenly into $n$?  That would be http://oeis.org/A007814.  If you were to skip the odd numbers, that would be the ruler function http://oeis.org/A001511 which is just the previous sequence after adding $1$ to every entry.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes and I want an equation for it.

Comment: And many equations for it are available in the link.  Scroll down to where it says `FORMULA` on the left

Comment: @JMoravitz yes but all of the ones I see depend on a different sequence or some abstract function

Comment: If you're looking at A007814, the very last formula in the list, by Gary Detlefs, seems as explicit as anyone could wish for.

Comment: @saulspatz it doesn't look like it works https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.  The "n mod 4" on the left means to get the actual answer, you have to keep dividing by $4$, so it's really more of a recursive formula after all.  However, the recursive formula that number $4$ on the formula list looks pretty good.

Comment: that is interesting

Comment: Would $\log_2(\gcd(x,2^x))$ count as a formula for you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm only if there is a non recursive formula for finding the $\gcd$ of something (but I don't think there is).